# How to get the CodeName for Worksheet in Excel using VSTO

Tags: excel, vsto

I did like this:

```
if (Excel._Application.ActiveWorkbook != null)
{
    List<WorksheetKeyValue> sheets = new List<WorksheetKeyValue>();
    foreach (object ws in ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets)
    {
        string strCodeName = ws.CodeName
    }
}
```

but `strCodeName` is an empty string when it supposed to be Sheet1, Sheet2, ..., SheetN like in VBA.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your condition, you can use Worksheet.CustomProperties as alternative to hold unique property of the sheet.

```
Worksheet ws = **current_sheet** as Worksheet;
ws.CustomProperties.Add("SheetID", **some_value**);
```

So, later on you can access them as

```
foreach (Excel.CustomProperty prop in ws.CustomProperties)
{
    if (prop.Name == "SheetID")
    {
       // access as prop.Value and prop.Name
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In VSTO, the `CodeName` property is an infra-structure property that you should not be using from your code.

From MSDN:

> This property supports the Visual
>   Studio Tools for Office infrastructure
>   and is not intended to be used
>   directly from your code.

Tell us what you are trying to accomplish, maybe there is an alternative way to do what you want.

Also, I noted from your code that you are using an Excel Addin. You can try to check if the `CodeName` property returns what you expect if you use an Excel Document Customization instead of an Excel Addin.

**Update:**
In order for you to uniquely tag a worksheet you could use a GUID and set it as a custom property of the worksheet using [`Worksheet.CustomProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.customproperties%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks @João Angelo. I'm trying to give each worksheet a unique property. so that later I can identify the right worksheet. Since I can't depend upon the worksheet Index, as it get changed.