# Attempting to get internal SheetId in VSTO for assistance in detecting a sheet rename

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I am currently caching information for formulas on sheets within my addin. When there is a change on the sheet this is captured so that the cache is updated. I have seen that there is no reliable way though to detect when the sheet name is changed so I did some work to see what changed when tabs are added, moved, etc.

In making my workbook at .zip file and looking at workbook.xml, I have found the following structure:

```
<sheets>
   <sheet r:id="rId1" sheetId="2" name="POC2"/>
   <sheet r:id="rId2" sheetId="1" name="POC1"/>
</sheets>
```

Is there anything that I am missing or does this approach seem solid?

The sheetId seems to be available and not be influenced by changing tab order and other operations. My thought is that I can use this internal id along with the sheet name. If the sheetId has a different name than what is in the cache, it would mean the sheet was renamed. If the sheetId no longer exists, the sheet was deleted, etc.

My question is if there is a way in VSTO to get hold of the sheetId attribute if my other ideas are valid.

Thanks,

Lee

Answer (score 0):

No, `sheetId` is just an attribute in the Excel Open XML definition so it can't be queried by code on an open Excel file.

What you want (and is the object model equivalent of sheetId) is `Worksheet.CodeName`.

A worksheet's CodeName will, when the worksheet object is created, be the same as the worksheet's Name. But it's not changed when the user changes the name of a worksheet. Nor can it be changed at run-time.

The only way CodeName can be changed is in the `Properties` window of a code editor (VBA or a VSTO document-level customization).

Comment: There are issues with the CodeName. In the SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388650/how-to-get-the-codename-for-worksheet-in-excel-using-vsto, it is possible that the CodeName is null.  I have seen a case where looking at the XML of the sheet has no CodeName property